# A generic method to invoke FluentValidation

Tags: generics, fluentvalidation

I am wishing to use FluentValidation (fluentvalidation.net) to validate user inputs for many different screens using a generic method.I need to pass it two objects : the datamodel containing the data to validate and the class containing the validation rules.

I wrote the following code:

```
Using FluentValidation;
.
.
.
    public class Validate<T> : AbstractValidator<T>
    {
        public void ValidateFormInput<U>(InputParams ip, object currentObject)
        {
            if (currentObject != null)
            {
                string resMess = "";

                FournisseurJoinedModel model = (FournisseurJoinedModel)currentObject;

                FournisseurValidator validator = new FournisseurValidator();
                ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(model);
               
             if (!results.IsValid)
                {
                   // do as needed...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

where T is the `FournisseurJoinedModel` (name, address, etc.) and U should be the class ref or class instance of the validation rules (`FournisseurValidator`).

This code works when invoked like this:

```
FournisseurJoinedModel co = (FournisseurJoinedModel)CurrentObject;
  
Validate<FournisseurJoinedModel> ic = new();

ic.ValidateFormInput<FournisseurValidator>(bl, co);
```

However When I use the T parameter to replace `FournisseurJoinedModel` and the U parameter to replace `FournisseurValidator` where they (still) occurs, I get an error saying that the parameters are wrong.

What is the right way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have created something like this for this case.

```
using FluentValidation;

public static class PropertyValidator<T, TK> where TK : AbstractValidator<T> {

private static readonly IValidator<T> Validator = Activator.CreateInstance<TK>();

public static void Validate(T toValidate) {
    var validationResult = Validator.Validate(toValidate);
    if (validationResult.IsValid is false)
        throw new ValidationException(validationResult.Errors);
 }
}
```

Then you can call your validator like this. I am doing my validation from within each classes constructor.

```
PropertyValidator<CharacterSpanStyle, CharacterSpanStyleValidator>.Validate(this);
```

And you ofc need your abstract validator to setup the rules

```
public class CharacterSpanStyleValidator : AbstractValidator<CharacterSpanStyle> {
public CharacterSpanStyleValidator()
{
    RuleFor(x => x.Position).GreaterThanOrEqualTo(0);
    RuleFor(x => x.Length).GreaterThanOrEqualTo(1);
    RuleFor(x => x.Style).NotEmpty();
}
```